# Best AMD settings for Minecraft?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, minecraft, amd-graphics

So I play Minecraft, and recently got my new AMD graphics card. I got the drivers installed but there are white lines all over the minecraft screen. I have screenshots of the AMD settings, and I'd love to know what to change to get the best quality out of my gaming. The settings are as follow:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]